# Heroku gem not working with RVM

Tags: ruby, heroku, installation

I'm following the Ruby on Rails tutorial at http://railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:1.4.1, and all is going well until I tried to get my app going on Heroku.

I installed heroku, that worked fine, but now when I run `heroku keys:add` or any other heroku command, I get the following error:

```
/home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>': 
no such file to load -- net/https. Try running apt-get install libopenssl-ruby (LoadError)
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.9.14/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.9.14/lib/heroku.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.9.14/bin/heroku:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I did what the error message said, and installed libopenssl-ruby, but heroku still didn't work.

I've done a search and found the following two pages which try to combat the heroku errors:
http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg05001.html
http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1534

I followed the instructions on these pages (which are the same), but heroku still doesn't work.

I usually do my work on windows, so everything is a bit new to me on ubuntu. Here's my ruby environment:

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sirswap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
     - /home/sirswap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I'm running ubuntu 10.04.

Any help or advice for next steps would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I'm actually really busy at the moment with job interviews and travel, so will have to respond a bit later to your answers to see what works for me :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, and I think it was caused by not installing all the ruby dependencies listed when you run:

```
$rvm requirements # it was earlier: rvm notes
```

Specifically, I executed [be sure to install aptitude first]:

```
$sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline5-dev curl git zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev
```

and after all that, I recompiled my ruby install (using `$rvm reinstall 1.9.2`) and heroku worked like a charm.

Comment: `rvm notes` is really important on *nix and Mac OS as there are missing dependencies usually that will keep parts of Ruby from working, only they won't be apparent until much later. Then we'll run into a problem and won't associate it with the install process. That's when we bang our heads against the wall for a while.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Following a Rails tutorial and the Heroku command puked, but installing missed dependencies and recompiling 1.9.2 worked like a charm.

Comment: To install **Aptitude**

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Answer (score 4):

Hey :)
Don't know if it's still relevant or whether this will work for you as well.. it did for me.

Had the exact same problem..

I also noticed when doing 
`$ rails console`

I was getting errors which indicated I had problems with Readline. 
Following http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ helped me fix all issues I was experiencing.

Answer (score 4):

I blew many hours on this yesterday.  Eventually, somewhat by chance (actually more like sheer desperation), I looked in the file /usr/bin/heroku

I noticed the first line of the script said

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

I changed this to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and it started working.  After re-installing ruby about 10 times and all that mucking around with openssl.  *rolleyes*

Comment: I had it working via rvm but didn't like its large environment changes (causing strange rvm-related errors to appear in other shell-invoking code). Removing rvm broke things, and lots of ruby/ruby-full/libssl tries didn't help. But this did! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped Gojomo.  I've also contacted the heroku team and have been working with them to try and understand this issue: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/174

Comment: By the way, the 'problem' as I see it, is that the heroku script force uses ruby 1.9.1.  when I install openssh etc, Ubuntu applies it to 1.9.2 - so the 1.9.1 error remains.  That is my (non-ruby-expert) understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also doing the Railstutorial on Ubuntu 10.10 and got the exact same error while trying to add Heroku keys. This solves it:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm pkg install openssl   
$ rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Answer (score 2):

Read my directions on [how to install RVM on Linux](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm).  You need to install libssl-dev or things like net/https won't work.  It's OK though, just install that and recompile your rubies.

Comment: Thanks, I just had this problem and installing libssl-dev and running extconf.rb fixed it

Comment: -1 for commercial about.com spam instead of real documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In your case "recompiling your rubies" can probably be done by issuing:

```
rvm install
```

Or alternatively you might make some progress by manually recompiling the openssl extension:

```
cd /home/sirswap/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb  
make  
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall ruby. I was same problem and fixed by reinstalling ruby.

```
rvm reinstall ruby 1.9.2
```