# Rails 3 Heroku deployment error, 'no such file to load'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just installed the latest Heroku gem v 2.3.3 and tried to run the following command:

```
heroku keys:add
```

and got a long list of errors:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require': no such file to load -- rest_client (LoadError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.3.3/lib/heroku/client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'.......
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Is the 'rest_client' gem installed in the current gemset?

Comment: I just installed it, restarted the server, and am still getting the error messages.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but I found this helpful last time I had issues from rvm:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626356/heroku-gem-not-working-with-rvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the 'rest-client' gem I also had to install the 'launchy' gem.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Change this file to add heroku-heroku-v2.6.1-1-g52550d0\heroku-heroku-52550d0\lib\heroku\client.rb following line at the top of the file

```
require 'rubygems'
```